# spark structured streaming + apache iceberg how appends can be idempotent

Tags: spark-structured-streaming, apache-iceberg

I'm using spark structured streaming to append to iceberg partitioned table. I need to use `foreachBatch` or `foreatch` as I'm using custom iceberg catalog implementation. (one from google biglake). Spark doc says `foreatchBatch` is at-least once means It can replay same `batch_id` batch in case of recovery from failure. I don't want duplicate records in iceberg table partition. How do I avoid this in best possible ways? couple options I can think of are:

1. use `merge into using.. when not matched insert *` and insert only when `id` of records doesn't match
2. store `batch_id` in a persistant set and check every new batch against it? I don't see any example of that. Not even sure if that's a right way to do idempotent updates.

Comment: Do you really mean to "append" or do you mean to insert into a table? If you don't mind about having overwrite snapshots which you can't readStream from, then foreachBatch and MERGE INTO is the way to go.